# How to list a double nested attribute values on 'index' view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 relevant tables to this problem: 'djobs', 'rigs', and 'photographers'. A djob has_many rigs, and a rig has_one photographer. Currently on my djob index screen I have a table where I am listing djob values and rig values, but I don't know how to also display photographer values.

I'm not really sure where to begin with this, so all I've tried is ensuring the models are associated correctly.

Here's my code:

djobs controller:

```
def index_photography
  @djobs = Djob.order(:id).joins(:rigs, :photographers)
end
```

djobs model:

```
class Djob < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rigs
  has_many :photographers, :through => :rigs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rigs, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photographers
end
```

djobs index view:

```
<tbody>
  <% @djobs.each do |djob| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_djob_path(djob, q: params[:q], :type => "photography") %></td>
      <td class="dotted" ><%= djob.jobtype %></td>
      <td class="dotted" ><% djob.rigs.each do |rig| %><%= rig.name %></br><% end %></td>
      <td class="dotted" ><% djob.rigs.photographers.each do |photographer| %><%= photographer.name %></br><% end %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

rig model:

```
class Rig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :djob
  has_one :photographer

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photographers
end
```

photographer model:

```
class Photographer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rig
end
```

This code gives me the error: "No association found for name `photographers'. Has it been defined yet?". All I want is for the table to display the photographer's name associated with that particular rig.

**Edit: I tried the suggest code from an answer below using this as my code:**

```
<td class="dotted" ><% djob.photographers.each do |photographer| %><%= photographer.name %></br><% end %></td>
```

and I also fixed my association model code for rigs and djobs.

And while it didn't give me any errors as I had before, there are no photographers showing at all. It's totally blank now. I don't know how to fix this issue. I know for a fact photographers are associated to rigs that are associated to the djob. And the rigs are displaying. So I'm not sure why the photographers aren't showing up at all for me. I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: It seems to me "double nested attribute values" isn't a thing.

Comment: I might have worded that really poorly. I'm not quite sure which terminology to use. I just meant displaying data from a table associated to the already associated table, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is here

`<td class="dotted" ><% djob.rigs.photographers.each do |photographer| %><%= photographer.name %></br><% end %></td>`

should probably be (to display all photographers associated with djob)

`<td class="dotted" ><% djob.photographers.each do |photographer| %><%= photographer.name %></br><% end %></td>`

or

`<td class="dotted" ><% djob.rigs.each do |rig| %><%= rig.photographer.name %></br><% end %></td>`

to display single photographer for each rig.

The reason of an error is that your `djob` model has many `photograpers` (plural form), but rig has only one `photograper`.